# Delay loop and pause it

Tags: android

I have this code. In my code I need to delay the operation start (it works fine) but in the operation I need to check InitInProcess() value. It if false then break loop, if true, wait 500ms and check again. But the resul I get that the checking breformed imediatly and not every 500ms.

```
Handler myHandler = new Handler();
        myHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {

                int test = 0;
                while (test!=20) 
                {
                    if (InitInProcess()) 
                        break;

                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(500);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {

                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    Log.d("MyApp", ""+test);


                    test++;
                }

            }
        }, 3000);
```

Log (look at the time):

```
    02-27 12:48:41.707: D/MyApp(10082): 0
    02-27 12:48:42.212: D/MyApp(10082): 1
    02-27 12:48:42.712: D/MyApp(10082): 2
    02-27 12:48:43.267: D/MyApp(10082): 3
    02-27 12:48:43.767: D/MyApp(10082): 4
    02-27 12:48:44.272: D/MyApp(10082): 5
    02-27 12:48:44.772: D/MyApp(10082): 6
    02-27 12:48:45.277: D/MyApp(10082): 7
    02-27 12:48:45.777: D/MyApp(10082): 8
    02-27 12:48:46.277: D/MyApp(10082): 9
    02-27 12:48:46.777: D/MyApp(10082): 10
    02-27 12:48:47.277: D/MyApp(10082): 11
    02-27 12:48:47.772: D/MyApp(10082): 12
    02-27 12:48:48.277: D/MyApp(10082): 13
    02-27 12:48:48.777: D/MyApp(10082): 14
    02-27 12:48:49.277: D/MyApp(10082): 15
    02-27 12:48:49.777: D/MyApp(10082): 16
    02-27 12:48:50.277: D/MyApp(10082): 17
    02-27 12:48:50.782: D/MyApp(10082): 18
    02-27 12:48:51.277: D/MyApp(10082): 19
```

Comment: Am i wrong??? these are 500ms steps.

Comment: 500ms is 0.5 sec, the all in 12:48

Comment: Oh.... sorry guys, I made stupid mistake because of tiredness, it is 500ms, I looked at the minutes. Rookie stuff!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private static final long RETRY_DELAY = 500;
private static final int RETRY_COUNT = 10;
private Handler myHandler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) {
            if (!InitInProcess() && msg.what>0) {
                myHandler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(msg.what-1, RETRY_DELAY);
            }
        }
    };

    myHandler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(RETRY_COUNT, RETRY_DELAY);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 int test = 0;
 while (test!=20){
       if (InitInProcess()) 
            break;

 try {
     myHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            test++;
            Log.d("MyApp", ""+test);
     },500);
  } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
  }
```

}

Comment: Where is 500ms delay?

Comment: use 500 inplace of 3000